# Regex for selecting all lines starting with=> Z:\Z_Data\

Tags: javascript, regex, select, text

I'm looking for Regex expression to find/selecting in a text all lines starting with

```
Z:\Z_Data\Zotero\_Dados\storage\
```

and ending in the last character of the same line.

Considering the following examples, just lines 1 and 3 should be selected:

```
Z:\Z_Data\Zotero\_Dados\storage\4SSK8KUM\etc.
The file Z:\Z_Data\Zotero\_Dados\storage\3V3K86CX\etc.
Z:\Z_Data\Zotero\_Dados\storage\3SSK9sdasdKUM\etc.
```

Many thanks,
Cadu

Comment: What do you mean by "ending in the last character of the same line?"

Comment: "ending in the last character of the same line?" = Where the line ends, before a new line start. In the examples I gave, all the content of Line 1 and Line 3 should be selected based on the prefix Z:\Z_Data\Zotero_Dados\storage\ which is in the beginning of the line.    Thanks!

Comment: My answer should apply to that

Comment: Scroll down to the "Answer" section of this page

Comment: @user3570966 If my answer helped you, please consider accepting as the correct answer, tks!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

this may help you:

```js
var html = "Z:\\Z_Data\\Zotero\\_Dados\\storage\\4SSK8KUM\\etc. \
The file Z:\\Z_Data\\Zotero\\_Dados\\storage\\3V3K86CX\\etc. \
Z:\\Z_Data\\Zotero\\_Dados\\storage\\3SSK9sdasdKUM\\etc.";

var myregexp = /^.*Z:\\Z_Data\\Zotero\\_Dados\\storage\\.*$/mg;
var match = myregexp.exec(html);
while (match != null) {
console.log(match[0]);
}
```

http://regex101.com/r/eP4vH3

Comment: This is actually incorrect. The first `.*` in the regexp will make it match `The file Z:\\Z_Data\\Zotero\\_Dados\\storage\\3V3K86CX\\etc. ` as displayed in your regex101.com link. @user3570966's solution in a comment to @explosion-pills answer is the correct one.

Comment: Since my edit was rejected, I'll just note here that the above code causes an infinite loop (should be something like `while (match = myregexp.exec(html)) {`). If you don't want your browser to hang, do not follow the JSFiddle link.

Comment: @Aurimas Your edit was rejected because you completely changed my answer. If you have a better answer fell free to add it.

Comment: As I mentioned above, the question is answered below, but the regexp you provide is incorrect (didn't attempt to edit that one) _and_ the solution you provide in the code block as well as JSFiddle causes an infinite loop, which hangs the browser (quite frustrating to users trying out your code). Thus, my edit was purely to prevent the inconvenience that an infinite loop causes and did not change your answer in any meaningful way otherwise.

Comment: @Aurimas, ***...did not change your answer in any meaningful way...*** you did, that's why your edit was rejected by the community.

Comment: I went ahead and fixed your infinite loop.  If there are fixes that need to be made to your regex, I encourage you to do so.  See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254599

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've removed the jsfiddle link earlier, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
^Z:\\Z_Data\\Zotero_Dados\\storage\\
```

The `^` anchors the expression to the start so the line *must* start with this expression.

I'm not sure what "ending in the last character..." means, but I assume it's something like you don't want any spaces after the path.  You can use:

```
^Z:\\Z_Data\\Zotero_Dados\\storage\\[^\s]*$
```

Comment: @user3570966 make sure to upvote/accept answers that help you

Comment: Note that you should be using the `m` flag to match at the beginning and end of the line in a multi-line string.